# Hibernate Query executed in @RestController out of @Transactional context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, hibernate-5.x

i'm writing an application in spring boot 2.0 and in i have a response of an Entity JPA Mapped with nested object dependency.

I load and an entity that is returned to the @RestController and included in response service.

I've noticed that a query executed by hibernate  when the object is in controller (out of transactions boundaries) to get nested obects (Lazy defined object reference)

How can it be possibile?

Comment: How sure are you that it's out of an active session? Can you pls post some code snippets?

Comment: by default open-session-in-view keeps active sessions until response is returned independently `@Transactional` boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in spring boot Open Session in View is enabled by default.

you have to disable it in `application.properties`

`spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`

Because jackson could also try to serialize referenced Lazy defined objects, you need to add jackson datatype for hibernate5 (because you are using spring boot 2)

```
@Bean
public Module hibernate5Module() {
    return new Hibernate5Module();
}
```

and in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

without version because it will be taken by spring-boot parent